# Probability of a Blizzard - Poisson vs Binomial vs Bayesian

Tags: regression, distributions, bayesian, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

My goal is to model data I have collected to compute the probability of a severe blizzard occurring in a given set of states (region).

Assume the US is broken into 3 regions that categorize the severity of blizzards occurring in those areas. For simplicity, let's just choose one region.

Collecting 66 years of data yields that 56 severe storms have occurred in this one region that consists of 10 states

- 56 storms/66 years = 0.84 storms per year (Binomial probability p)
- 56 storms/10 states = 5.6 storms per state (Poisson mean μ)

> *[Binomial Data]*
>
> - Number of Trials (n) = 100
> - Number of Successes out of Trials (k) = 1 to 100 with increments of 1
> - Probability of Success = 0.84
> - Probability of Failure = 0.16
>
> *[Poisson Data]*
>
> - Mean Successes per Year (μ) = 5.6
> - Test Interval (x) = 0 to 25 with increments of 1

I've created and plotted both Binomial and Poisson distributions **separately** using the above bullet data.

However, I'm confused on the modeling aspect now.

1. From a presentation standpoint, spitting out a number like on a college exam seems unusual and fruitless. I want to learn how to model this data but I don't know how.
2. Should there be a transition from the Binomial data into the Poisson data to create a uniform function? Binomial is telling me whether or not there will be a storm while the Poisson is showing the probability of a storm occurring given the average rate. Should these 2 distributions have a relation like this? How would you go about doing this?

Comment: It might well be more than one storm in a year, so the poisson distribution seems more natural than the binomial.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a [Cox process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox_process). (Or a [Poisson Point Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) in any case.)